# Tart Taste to Hot Bath method canned Vegetable soup

Tags: food-safety, storage-method

Why does my homemade vegetable soup cooked for at least 3 hours and then I put into canning jars in a hot bath for 45 minutes taste tart? What can I add to take the tart taste away? It has been sitting for about a month on shelf. Smelled okay when I opened up to warm up to eat.

Comment: What's in the soup? Preferably the whole recipe.

Comment: Did you taste it before sealing the jars? Was the tartness always there, or did it only develop after the soup had been stored for a while?